# MYSQL Optimize tables on Innodb in production environment advice

Tags: mysql

According to mysqltunner.pl I have 177 Fragmented tables. I have over 5000 tables and 200 databases.

If I run optimize table on each of them, do you think I should take down the application to prevent reads and writes while I do this? I know that optimize locks the table, but if it is a pretty quick operation I don't know if it was cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize a table without interrupting service by using [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html):

```
$ pt-online-schema-change --alter="ENGINE=InnoDB" --execute D=sakila,t=actor
```

Also, MySQL 5.6.17 supports OPTIMIZE as an [online DDL change](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html), allowing concurrent DML.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO when you maintain your DB in this invasive way, you must stop the application.

Send a communication to your customers so they be able to plan their activities.

You can't stop your application when the maintenance task are very fastes.